# how to insert gmail composing button in my website

Tags: php, gmail

i have gmail mail icon link.when i click the link it will open gmail compose message(when user already login) otherwise it will goto gmail login page.

Exatly like mynthra site

http://www.myntra.com/Shirts/Mast-Harbour/Mast-Harbour-Men-Navy-Erida-Slim-Smart-Casual-Shir/123607/buy?nav_id=7&searchQuery=men-casual-shirts&serp=2&uq=false#!

in above link,below the product image have gmail icon is there,same operation i need

Comment: ...what have you tried? What is your exact question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search and here is your answer. Just use the given URL instead of `mailto:`

Example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=youremail@gmail.com&body=my-text">Click here to email</a>
```

[Source](http://azgtech.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/replacing-mailto-with-gmail-compose-link/)

Comment: Inside the body of the email or the anchor? Please be more specific. Also, just trying things out! Remember, google is your friend! 99.9% of the time you'll find your answer quicker by searching first.

Comment: <a target="_blank" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=youremail@gmail.com&body=test<br>firstname<br>lastname">Click here to email</a>   when i am using <br> tag it also dispalyed in body section of email

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new line with `%0a` instead of `\n` for gmail and some other email clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail with subject. Open with popup Modal Box:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" async >
    function genericSocialShare(url){
       window.open(url,'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=648,height=395');
       return true;
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:genericSocialShare('https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=youremail@gmail.com&su=yoursubject&body=my-text&ui=2&tf=1&pli=1')"></a></li>
```