# How to make a share button to Gmail in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, gmail

I have a messaging web app in AngularJS and I had already implemented sharing messages with standard mail clients with "mailto" like this:

```
<a class="list-group-item"
   href="mailto:usuario@compartir.com?&
   subject=Notificacion de Notificaciones+&
   body={{mail.alert}} - {{mail.content}}">
   <div class="media-box">
     <div class="pull-left">
       <em class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x text-warning"></em>
     </div>
     <div class="media-box-body clearfix">
       <h4 style="padding: 5px; margin: 0px;" class="m0">Correo</h4>
     </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

That opens whatever email client the user has installed.

The problem is: **if the user does not have an email client it does nothing.**

What I want to do is a way to make a button to share directly to email via web browser, the same way you would share with Twitter or any social network.

Is there a way to do this or Gmail (or others like Yahoo, Outlook, etc.) doesn't allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `mailto` it's up to the settings of the browser/os to open the correct mail client. If you want to use gmail you'l need to replace `mailto` with an actual link.

This question will help-

[how to insert gmail composing button in my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923536/how-to-insert-gmail-composing-button-in-my-website)