# Create a Gmail share link

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, gmail, gmail-api

I would like to put a button on my one page web application that allows a user to send a link through Gmail. I found that some websites such as addthis.com provide such a button, however this button automatically uses the link from the url bar. Since I have a one page web application the link in the url bar will always be the same. I need to be able to to put the link in the button myself (which is possible with, for example, the Facebook and Twitter share buttons).

How can I create a Gmail button that can be used to share a link?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just get an image you want and link it via html like a regular link?

Comment: That would be fine but what HTML code can I use to allow a user to send a link through Gmail? I am looking for something like this: <a href="mailto:?body=http://url-to-be-shared.com"></a>. But instead that this link opens Outlook it should open Gmail.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923536/how-to-insert-gmail-composing-button-in-my-website

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work great on a desktop. However it doesn't seem to work on a mobile phone. Does anyone have an idea what url I could use to share a link through Gmail using a mobile phone?

Comment: What if someone doesn't have gmail?

Answer (score 9):

On Button click write a function and do this inside the function

```
let url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=&su=Your+Subject+here&body='+msgbody+'&ui=2&tf=1&pli=1';

window.open(url, 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=648,height=395');
```

The url will generate a link to open a gmail tab with auto filled subject and in in place of msgbody you can put your url you want to share.

Comment: is it possible to add an image to the body? thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]Gmail Sharable Link Creator

**Site Link: [GmailLink.GitHub.io](https://gmaillink.github.io/)**

Steps to Follow to generate the Link

1. Get the **Message ID** Of Mail Thread (**Mail > 3 dot menu in Right side (⋮) > Click on Show Original > See the MessageID**).
2. Copy the **Message-Id**
3. Use the MessageId & click On **Submit** to generate the Mail Sharable Link.

Answer (score 0):

Try the official [Google+ Share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/). There's a field there where you'll specify the "URL to share". Since you're only using one URL, this might work in your favor.
[image]

Comment: This Feature was deleted by google